# pybrain training neural network, total error very low, percent error very high, why?

Tags: machine-learning, pybrain

what does it mean if i get a total error of like 0.02 as the training epochs are run, but then percenterror on trainer.testOnClassData() is like 95% ?

Comment: Hello user2506851, total error like 0.02 and high percent error may mean high overfitting. Maybe you have wrong loss function? Do you make classification or regression? Do you specify any validation dataset? What loss function do you use? Do you have any background in machine learning?

Comment: yes sorry my question was specific to the pybrain tools .. the history of the question was lost .. i apologize, thank you